# Historic (and prehistoric) dates in Ruby

Tags: ruby, numeric-precision, date-format

In Ruby, is there a standard class or gem to work with dates that can be - but are not required to be - historical in nature? The dates have precision (to the nearest million years, decade, century, year, month, second, etc).  For example:

- 20th century
- 2000's
- 5th century, BCE
- 1920's
- June, 1945
- 4.6 million years ago
- 1988-07-11 06:45:08

Comment: seems in plans, for me exactly =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't manage to find anything that met my needs, so created the `CarbonDate` Ruby gem.

- https://rubygems.org/gems/carbon_date
- https://github.com/bradleymarques/carbon_date